# Is there a way to see how SQL Server 2012 defines new identities?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, identity, database-internals

On `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)`, is there a way to see what mechanism SQL Server uses to calculate the new identity values for tables created by `SELECT INTO`?

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
-- Create our base table
CREATE TABLE dbo.A
(A_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
x1 INT,
noise1 int DEFAULT 1,
noise2 char(1) DEFAULT 'S',
noise3 date DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
noise4 bit DEFAULT 0);

-- Create random data between the range of [0-3]
INSERT INTO dbo.A(x1)
SELECT s1000.n FROM
( SELECT TOP (10) n = 1 FROM sys.columns) AS s10 -- 10
CROSS JOIN
( SELECT TOP (10) n = 1 FROM sys.columns) AS s100 -- 10 * 10
CROSS JOIN
( SELECT TOP (10) n = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 4 FROM sys.columns) AS s1000; -- 100 * 10

SELECT * FROM dbo.A ORDER BY A_ID DESC;
```

In my case, the results are:

[image: dbo.A results]

And running

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('A')
```

returns

> Checking identity information: current identity value '1000', current
>   column value '1000'.

---

**Create new table**

When we select a subset into a new table, it creates a new current identity value:

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM dbo.A WHERE x1 = 0;
```

The highest value in the identity column of this new table is 998 and when we check it's next identity:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('#temp')
```

> Checking identity information: current identity value '998', current
>   column value '998'.

---

**How?**

How are these identity values inserted into the new table with the highest value correctly set as the current identity value of the new table?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SELECT INTO` has two phases (not visible in execution plans).

First, it creates a table that matches the metadata of the query used to create it. This happens in a system transaction, so the (empty) created table will continue to exist even if the `SELECT INTO` is wrapped in a user transaction that is rolled back. At the end of the first phase, we have an empty table that includes a column named *A_ID* with the identity property.

The second phase performs an insert into the table the first phase created. This insert is done with *identity_insert* semantics, so the identity values from the source table end up in the destination, unchanged. The *highest value actually inserted* is set as the last value used. You can use `IDENT_CURRENT` or *sys.indentity_columns* to see it.

Unrelated, but semi-interesting fact: There is a small window between creating the table and starting to perform the insert, where the source table in the query is not protected by a schema stability lock. If a concurrent process happens to change the schema of the source table (after the target has been created, but before the insert starts), error 539 is raised:

> Schema changed after the target table was created. Rerun the Select Into query.